# Chrome Extension popup size not changing

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My popup.html file is in this format (This is the entire file):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="background:#000000;overflow: hidden;">

<canvas id='ctx' width='750' height='450' style='border:white solid 2px;'></canvas>
<canvas id='ctx2' width='150' height='90' style='position:absolute;top:360px;left:20px;border:1px solid black;'></canvas>
<div id='pauseMenu'>

    <div class='menuHeader'>
        <button style='color:white;background:black' id='pause'>P to Resume</button>
        <button id='trackB'>Track</button>
        <button id='modelB'>Model</button>
        <button id='controlB'>Controls</button>
        <button id='settingB'>Settings</button>
    </div>

    <div class='menu' id='track' style='display:flex;'>
        <div style='flex:25%;'>
            <p>Track:</p>
            <select id='tracks'></select><br>
            <p id='selectedTrack'></p>
            <div class='smallBut' id='reset'>Reset</div>
        </div>
        <div style='flex:75%;'>
            <img id='map' src='' width='500' height='300' style='position:absolute;right:10;top:80px;'>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='menu' id='model' style='display:flex;'>
        <div style='flex:25%;'>
            <p>Car:</p>
            <select id='models'></select><br>
            <p id='selectedModel'></p>
            <div class='smallBut' id='showAdvanced' style='width:100px'>Show Advanced</div>
        </div>
        <div style='flex:75%;'>
            <img id='modelImg' src='' width='258' height='120' style='position:absolute;right:10;top:80px;margin-right:100px;background:white;'>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu control" id="settings" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
        <table style='font-size: 12px;'>
            <tr>
                <td>Cur. best ghost:</td>
                <td><textarea id='bghost'></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prev. lap ghost:</td>
                <td><textarea id='pghost'></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Import ghost:</td>
                <td><textarea id='ighost'></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Reset all times:</td>
                <td><button id='resall' style='color:white;background:black;'>Reset</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Framerate (fps):</td>
                <td>
                    <select id='fps'>
                        <option value='1'>120</option>
                        <option value='2'>60 (rec)</option>
                        <option value='3'>40</option>
                        <option value='4'>30</option>
                        <option value='6'>20</option>
                        <option value='8'>15</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Show Best For:</td>
                <td>
                    <select id='best'>
                        <option value='0'>Ferrari F1</option>
                        <option value='1'>Bugatti Chiron</option>
                        <option value='2'>Toyota Corolla</option>
                        <option value='3'>Red Bull x2010</option>
                        <option value='4'>Lamborghini Huracan</option>
                        <option value='5'>BMW 7-series</option>
                        <option value='6'>Porsche 919</option>
                        <option value='7'>None</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Post-pause Countdown:</td>
                <td>
                    <select id='cdown'>
                        <option value='3'>0 seconds</option>
                        <option value='2'>1 second</option>
                        <option value='1'>2 seconds</option>
                        <option value='0'>3 seconds</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Show Mini-map:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="minimap">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Max Drift Mark Length:</td>
                <td>
                    <select id='driftMark'>
                        <option value='0'>0 (Off)</option>
                        <option value='500'>500</option>
                        <option value='1000'>1000 (rec)</option>
                        <option value='2000'>2000</option>
                        <option value='5000'>5000</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Smoke Density:</td>
                <td>
                    <select id='smokeDensity'>
                        <option value='0'>0 (Off)</option>
                        <option value='1'>1 (rec)</option>
                        <option value='2'>2</option>
                        <option value='3'>3</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Max Smoke Volume:</td>
                <td>
                    <select id='smokeVolume'>
                        <option value='0'>0 (Off)</option>
                        <option value='1000'>1000</option>
                        <option value='2000'>2000</option>
                        <option value='5000'>5000 (rec)</option>
                        <option value='10000'>10000</option>
                        <option value='20000'>20000</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="menu control" id='controls'>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Up arrow</td>
                <td>Acceleration</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Left/right arrow</td>
                <td>Steering</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Down arrow</td>
                <td>Braking</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Q</td>
                <td>+ Traction Control</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>A</td>
                <td>- Traction Control</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>X</td>
                <td>Automatic/Manual toggle</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>W</td>
                <td>Up shift</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>S</td>
                <td>Down shift</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>P</td>
                <td>Pause toggle</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shift</td>
                <td>Reset timer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>R</td>
                <td>Reset drift marks</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>T</td>
                <td>Reset car</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Space</td>
                <td>E-Brake</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src='main.js'></script>
</body>
<style>
html{
    overflow: hidden;width:760px;height:450px;
}
*{
    color:white;
}
.control{
    column-count:2;
}
td{
    padding:10px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: white;
    margin:10px;
}
button{
    border:none;
    background:white;
    width:137.25px;
    height:50px;
    color:black;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-family:'Georgia';
    font-size:15px;
}
button:hover{
    background:gray;
}
textarea{
    color:black;
}
canvas {margin: 0; overflow: hidden}
#pauseMenu{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    width:700px;
    height:400px;
    left:30px;
    top:30px;
}
.menuHeader{
    width:700px;
    height:50px;
    background:black;
    z-index: 100;
    border:white 2px solid;

}
.menu{
    width:700px;
    height:350px;
    background: black;
    z-index: 99;
    margin-top:3px;
    border:white 2px solid;
}
.smallBut{
    border-radius:2px;background:white;width:50px;height:20px;padding-top:5px;color:black;text-align:center;margin:auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.smallBut:hover{
    background:gray;
}
p{
    font-family:Georgia;
    font-size:15px;
    padding:10px;
    background:white;
    color:black;
    text-align:center
}
select{
    margin:auto;
    padding:10px;
    color:black;
}
b{
    color:black;
}
</style>
</html>
```

There are two problems I am facing:

1. Even though I have overflow:hidden;, a scrollbar still appears
2. A bit of the right of the canvas gets cut off even though the width of the body/html is more than that of the canvas. No matter how big I make the width of the body/html, the size of the popup doesn't actually change.

I can give more details if you want, please help.

Comment: Yes, Please provide a working example of your problem, right now can't figure out the actual problem.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to do that but the big problem is that the popup size is smaller than the canvas so it is cutting part of the canvas off, even though the dimensions of the html tag are bigger.

Comment: Remove `position: fixed`.

Comment: Can you add your js file or make example in snippet. the above code cant help anything

Comment: Please provide the total snippet so that stack community can help you better.